# Jquery .show Issue on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form, and when certain inputs are filled another div will display beneath the form. The following is the code:

```
<form>

<div class="fieldtitle">Full Name:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="fullname" id="fullname" />
<div class="fieldtitle">Email:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="email" id="emailfield" />
<div class="fieldtitle">Contact No:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="contact" id="contact" />

</form>

<div id="demo1" style="width:300px; display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#formarea").keyup(function(){
    if($(fullname).val() && $(emailfield).val() && $(contact).val() && $(quantity).val()) {
        $("#demo1").show();
        if($.browser.msie){
           $('#demo1').css({"visibility":"visible"});
        }
    } else {
        $("#demo1").hide();
    }

});

</script>
```

It is working on all browsers, except for IE - any suggestions as how to solve this?

Comment: Does IE not work at all or just not how you expect?  Is there an error of any kind?

Comment: Whats this for? `if($.browser.msie){
           $('#demo1').css({"visibility":"visible"});
        }`

Comment: jquery.show() method should be cross browser compatible on its own

Comment: hey man where is element with id of **formarea**?

Comment: Nothing happens in IE - the div remains hidden.

Comment: Use the IDs of the elements you are referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html is missing the quantity field, which will cause logic issues in the Javascript.

```
<form>
    <div class="fieldtitle">Full Name:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="fullname" id="fullname" />
    <div class="fieldtitle">Email:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="email" id="emailfield" />
    <div class="fieldtitle">Contact No:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="contact" id="contact" />
    <div class="fieldtitle">Quantity:* </div><input type="text" value="" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
</form>

    <div id="demo1" style="width:300px; display:none;">Test</div>
```

The Javascript binds the event to the wrong element. It should bind to`inputs` instead of the form.  Also the selectors passed in for each input should be string literals using the css id selector.

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    if($("#fullname").val() && $("#emailfield").val() && $("#contact").val() && $("#quantity").val()) {
        $("#demo1").show();
    } else {
        $("#demo1").hide();
    }
});
```

There is also no need for the IE conditional.  Jquery's `show()/hide()` methods are cross browser compatible.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DEfVS/1/

Answer (score 1):

IE dont like suggested id or name selector, you dont use it in the right way. Specify which selector you are targetting.

e.g:
Replace

```
$(fullname)
```

With

```
$('#fullname')
```

And so on...

By the way, cannot see in your sample code any form with ID 'formarea'.
And remove this: `if($.browser.msie){...}`  its useless.